# steady state conditions

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the steady state value of variables in `NDSolve` but the variables have oscillation. Do you help me?

```
H = .3;
KD = .01;
Ra = .0019;
RD = .0141;
Rf = .00041;
RQ = .0136;
Lmd =(*.73*).448;
Lmq =(*.36*).248;
Ld =(*.85*).45;
Lq =(*.48*).25;
Lf = .9349;
LD = .89;
LQ = .4629;
vf = .00123;
Tm = 3.8;
xz = .2;
wi = 314;
Rdc = .05;
Ldc = 2; 
cm = .82*10^-3;
cn = .82*10^-6;
Req = .003;
Leq = .003;
Rm = 5;
Rn = 15;
α = π/6;
β = (13 π)/18;
kv = (3 Sqrt[2])/π;
ki = π/(3 Sqrt[2]);
tf = 3160;



NL = NDSolveValue[{
y9[t] == -Ra y1[t] - y13[t] (-Lq y2[t] + Lmq y7[t]) - Ld y1'[t] + 
  Lmd (y5'[t] + y6'[t]),

y10[t] == -Ra y2[t] - Lq y2'[t] + Lmq y7'[t] + 
  y13[t] (-Ld y1[t] + Lmd (y5[t] + y6[t])),

-y1[t] + y9[t]/Rm + cm y9'[t] - cm y13[t] y10[t] + 
  y8[t]/ki Sin[y14[t] + α] == 0,

-y2[t] + cm y10'[t] + y10[t]/ Rm + cm y13[t] y9[t] + 
  y8[t]/ki Cos[y14[t] + α] == 0,

RD y6[t] + LD y6'[t] + Lmd (y5'[t] - y1'[t]) == 0,

RQ y7[t] + LQ y7'[t] - Lmq y2'[t] == 0,


-kv (y9[t] Sin[y14[t]] + y10[t] Cos[y14[t]]) + (Rdc + 
     3/π (xz + Leq) y13[t]) y8[t] + Ldc  y8'[t] - kv y12[t] ==
  0,

vf == Rf y5[t] + Lf y5'[t] + Lmd (y6'[t] - y1'[t]),


-y4[t] + cn y12'[t] + 1/ Rn y12[t] + y8[t]/ki Cos[β] == 0,
-y3[t] + cn y11'[t] + 1/ Rn y11[t] + y8[t]/ki Sin[β] == 0,

y11[t] == -Req y3[t] - Leq y3'[t],

y12[t] == -Req y4[t] - Leq y4'[t],

Tm + y1[t] (-Lq y2[t] + Lmq y7[t]) - 
  y2[t] (-Ld y1[t] + Lmd (y5[t] + y6[t])) == 
 KD y13[t] + 2 H wi y13'[t],

y13[t] - 1 == y14'[t],


y1[-tf] == -2.317628024, y2[-tf] == 0.6335502, 
y3[-tf] == 1.82503593, y4[-tf] == -1.531386979, 
y5[-tf] == 2.46216090, y6[-tf] == -0.007279062, 
y7[-tf] == -0.000808, y8[-tf] == 1.764484804, 
y9[-tf] == 0.163025432, y10[-tf] == 2.14061, 
y11[-tf] == -0.0054750306, y12[-tf] == 0.00459409, y13[-tf] == 1, 
y14[-tf] == .5}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, 
y12, y13, y14}, {t, -tf, 0}
, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

Comment: "Steady state" and "oscillatory behavior" are sort of mutually exclusive. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to fix state variable at certain value and find steady state value of variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Which variables do you want held fixed? for which variables do you want to find steady-state values? What did you mean by oscillatory behavior and how does that not conflict with the notion of steady state? Etc. Can you reduce your problem to a simpler one that will be easier to understand? As it is, there is a lot of code there that is hard to decipher.

Comment: I want all variables to be fixed.

Comment: The code posted trows an error: `NDSolveValue::ndsz: "At t == -3160., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected."`

Comment: @george2079. It didn't throw that error for me, interestingly enough.

Comment: The code has not error.

Comment: must be a version issue. I checked again and still get that error with 10.1

Comment: @MichaelE2. Yeah, I mean, I guess I wouldn't call that a steady state, but clearly that's a matter of semantics, since it is a "simple" function that the solution settles to in the long time limit. However, it seemed to me that the OP meant a "true" steady state, and I was just trying to get them to clarify, since clearly the two cases are *very* different.

Answer (score 3):

One can get candidate values by solving for derivatives equal to zero.

```
eqs = {y9[t] == -0.0019` y1[t] - 
     y13[t] (-0.25` y2[t] + 0.248` y7[t]) - 
     0.45` Derivative[1][y1][t] + 
     0.448` (Derivative[1][y5][t] + Derivative[1][y6][t]), 
   y10[t] == -0.0019` y2[t] + 
     y13[t] (-0.45` y1[t] + 0.448` (y5[t] + y6[t])) - 
     0.25` Derivative[1][y2][t] + 
     0.248` Derivative[1][y7][t], -y1[t] - 0.00082` y10[t] y13[t] + (
     3 Sqrt[2] Sin[\[Pi]/6 + y14[t]] y8[t])/\[Pi] + y9[t]/5 + 
     0.00082` Derivative[1][y9][t] == 0, 
   y10[t]/5 - y2[t] + (3 Sqrt[2] Cos[\[Pi]/6 + y14[t]] y8[t])/\[Pi] + 
     0.00082` y13[t] y9[t] + 0.00082` Derivative[1][y10][t] == 0, 
   0.0141` y6[t] + 
     0.448` (-Derivative[1][y1][t] + Derivative[1][y5][t]) + 
     0.89` Derivative[1][y6][t] == 0, 
   0.0136` y7[t] - 0.248` Derivative[1][y2][t] + 
     0.4629` Derivative[1][y7][t] == 
    0, -((3 Sqrt[2]
        y12[t])/\[Pi]) + (0.05` + 0.1938507206859285` y13[t]) y8[
       t] - (3 Sqrt[
      2] (Cos[y14[t]] y10[t] + Sin[y14[t]] y9[t]))/\[Pi] + 
     2 Derivative[1][y8][t] == 0, 
   0.00123` == 
    0.00041` y5[t] + 0.9349` Derivative[1][y5][t] + 
     0.448` (-Derivative[1][y1][t] + Derivative[1][y6][t]), 
   y12[t]/15 - y4[t] - (3 Sqrt[2] Sin[(2 \[Pi])/9] y8[t])/\[Pi] + 
     8.199999999999999`*^-7 Derivative[1][y12][t] == 0, 
   y11[t]/15 - y3[t] + (3 Sqrt[2] Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] y8[t])/\[Pi] + 
     8.199999999999999`*^-7 Derivative[1][y11][t] == 0, 
   y11[t] == -0.003` y3[t] - 0.003` Derivative[1][y3][t], 
   y12[t] == -0.003` y4[t] - 0.003` Derivative[1][y4][t], 
   3.8` - y2[t] (-0.45` y1[t] + 0.448` (y5[t] + y6[t])) + 
     y1[t] (-0.25` y2[t] + 0.248` y7[t]) == 
    0.01` y13[t] + 188.4` Derivative[1][y13][t], -1 + y13[t] == 
    Derivative[1][y14][t]};
eqss = TrigExpand[
   eqs /. Equal :> Subtract /. Derivative[_][__][__] :> 0];
eqss2 = N[
  Append[eqss /. {Cos[y14[t]] -> c14, Sin[y14[t]] -> s14}, 
   c14^2 + s14^2 - 1]]

(* {0. + 0.0019 y1[t] - 0.25 y13[t] y2[t] + 0.248 y13[t] y7[t] + y9[t], 
 0. + y10[t] + 0.45 y1[t] y13[t] + 0.0019 y2[t] - 
  0.448 y13[t] y5[t] - 0.448 y13[t] y6[t], -1. y1[t] - 
  0.00082 y10[t] y13[t] + 0.675237237118 c14 y8[t] + 
  1.16954520185 s14 y8[t] + 0.2 y9[t], 
 0.2 y10[t] - 1. y2[t] + 1.16954520185 c14 y8[t] - 
  0.675237237118 s14 y8[t] + 0.00082 y13[t] y9[t], 0. + 0.0141 y6[t], 
 0. + 0.0136 y7[t], -1.35047447424 c14 y10[t] - 
  1.35047447424 y12[t] + 0.05 y8[t] + 0.193850720686 y13[t] y8[t] - 
  1.35047447424 s14 y9[t], 0.00123 - 0.00041 y5[t], 
 0.0666666666667 y12[t] - 1. y4[t] - 0.868068259237 y8[t], 
 0.0666666666667 y11[t] - 1. y3[t] + 1.03452346656 y8[t], 
 0. + y11[t] + 0.003 y3[t], 0. + y12[t] + 0.003 y4[t], 
 3.8 - 0.01 y13[t] + 0.2 y1[t] y2[t] - 0.448 y2[t] y5[t] - 
  0.448 y2[t] y6[t] + 0.248 y1[t] y7[t], -1. + y13[t], -1. + c14^2 + 
  s14^2} *)
```

This next part might simply hang...

```
NSolve[eqss]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Daniel Lichtblau.

Answer (score 3):

Let `eqns` be the differential equations and `ics` be the initial conditions in the OP's system.

Then, as in Daniel Lichtblau's approach, we can set the derivatives equal to zero and solve the equations, but instead, since the ODE is nonlinear, let's use `FindRoot`. it is not clear how many steady state solutions there might be, if any, or whether the initial conditions `ics` yields a solution that converges to a steady state.

```
vars = {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13, y14};

SeedRandom[0];
yss = FindRoot[
  eqns /. {Derivative -> (((0 &) &) &)} /. (f_)[t] :> f, 
  Transpose[{vars, RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 14]}], MaxIterations -> 500]
(*
  {y1 -> -1.19092, y2 -> 2.39542, y3 -> -1.8437, y4 -> 1.54705, 
   y5 -> 3., y6 -> 0., y7 -> -1.01641*10^-28, y8 -> -1.78253, 
   y9 -> 0.601119, y10 -> 1.87536, y11 -> 0.00553109, 
   y12 -> -0.00464114, y13 -> 1., y14 -> 8.32596}
*)

ss = NDSolve[{eqns, Through[vars[0]] == (vars /. yss)}, 
   vars, {t, 0, 1000}];

Plot[Through[vars[t]] /. ss // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, we seem to have found one steady state.  Note that adding a multiple of `2 Pi` to `y14` will yield others.  A random search produces four (module `2 Pi` for `y14`).  That seems to be all there is for variables whose absolute value is less than `100`.

```
trials = Quiet@Table[Check[
      MapAt[Mod[#, 2 Pi] &,
       vars /. FindRoot[
         eqns /. {Derivative -> (((0 &) &) &)} /. (f_)[t] :> f,
         Transpose[{vars, RandomReal[{-100, 100}, 14]}]],
       -1],
      {}],
     100] /. {} :> Sequence[];

DeleteDuplicates[trials, Norm@Subtract[##] < 10^-8 &]
(*
{{1.53149, 3.6523, -2.88882, 2.424, 3., 0., 8.30561*10^-29, -2.79297, 0.910165,
  0.647892, 0.00866645, -0.00727201, 1., 2.98402},
 {-1.19092, 2.39542, 1.8437, -1.54705, 3., 0., -8.50086*10^-26, 1.78253, 0.601119,
  1.87536, -0.00553109, 0.00464114, 1., 5.18436},
 {1.53149, 3.6523, 2.88882, -2.424, 3., 0., -6.76742*10^-29, 2.79297, 0.910165,
  0.647892, -0.00866645, 0.00727201, 1., 6.12562},
 {-1.19092, 2.39542, -1.8437, 1.54705, 3., 0., -7.80903*10^-25, -1.78253,
  0.601119, 1.87536, 0.00553109, -0.00464114, 1., 2.04277}}
*)
```